# How to make Eclipse break String literal with + operator in next line?

Tags: eclipse

---

(Edited) NOTE: this question is NOT about how Eclipse's code formatter wrap long String literals.  It is the behavior of MANUALLY breaking/wrapping String literal

---

The default behavior when I break a String literal by hitting enter inside the literal, is Eclipse will append `" +` at the place I hit enter, and start the rest of my line in next line, with `"` prefixed.

```
                            // v ENTER HERE
String longString = "abcdefghij|klmno";

String longString = "abcdefghij" +
        "klmno";
```

However, normal coding style practice suggests line wrap before operator.  Is there any way that I can tell Eclipse to break my String like this?

```
String longString = "abcdefhij"
        + "klmno";
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289076/change-how-eclipse-formatter-wraps-long-strings

Comment: @DeepakAzad I am in fact not talking about the formatter setting.  Even you have formatter setting with wrap before operator, it didn't change the behavior that eclipse wrap line when you are breaking a String literal by hitting Enter key.  That's what I am looking for : How to make String literal line wrapping behavior align with Formatter's setting.

Comment: @AdrianShum: Did you _try_ the proposed duplicate? Perhaps the formatter settings affect your case also. If that is _not_ the case and you _did_ try, please modify your question. This might bring more people to think about your problem.

Comment: I did and that's why in my question, I am focusing only in manually breaking string literal.  If you have had a try on the seems-to-be duplicate, you will find an interesting phenomenon: code formatter will completely reformat the result of manual breaking string literal.  Please advise how should I modify my question coz I thought I have have emphasized enough that's about manual breaking of string literal (and not about formatter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this is one missing feature of Eclipse.

Currently this issue is tracked under Eclipse's issue tracker :
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=48433

---

Update: I am now using Eclipse 4.3, and found that this feature is now available.  Position of `+` operator when you are manually breaking a long String will now follows your code formatter setting.

Comment: where is this option?

Comment: No special options for me.  The + operator line breaking simply follow what I set in code formatter.

Answer (score 6):

In 4.3 you can control this setting with the *Wrap before operator* checkbox for *Binary expressions*.

[image: Formatter settings in Eclipse Luna]

Comment: I believe such setting have always been there in code formatter.  Just in case you didn't follow the question, in very first line in question I have already mentioned: `NOTE: this question is NOT about how Eclipse's code formatter wrap long String literals. It is the behavior of MANUALLY breaking/wrapping String literal`  In older version of Eclipse, code formatting for manually breaking long line literal does not follow code formatter settings

Comment: I just answered to save somebody some time because this option in the formatter settings is a bit obfuscated. For me it was not clear that "Binary Expressions" affects string wrapping.